# Looking to extract data between parentheses in a string via MYSQL

Tags: mysql, regex

Can someone please help. I have been searching and encountered/modified this code I am getting a 1 or 0 as a result. 1 if there is something between () and 0 if there is not. I am looking to find exactly what is between them not if there is something. So if I have a string in afield that looks like this:  "ABC (989) Hello" currently I get 1 as my result I would like to get "989". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

select *, OUTCNTCTNOTE regexp '[(]|\*\[)]' as test
from trcalls.callcoding;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select substr(columnname,instr(columnname,"(") + 1, instr(columnname,")")) as temp from mytable
```

something close, I tested this. Please see if this helps!

Comment: Thanks. This is very close. I get everything after the open parenthesis, Now I just need to figure out how to get rid of the close and everything after it and I will be set.

Comment: if you find the answer was usefull, please consider to accept this answer. Thank you.

Comment: Here is what I ended up using:  select SUBSTRING_INDEX(substr(<Field>,instr(<Field>,"(") + 1), ')', 1) as temp from <Table>;

Comment: @StephenDeLillo 's answer should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 6):

To complete the first answer, because the third parameter passed to substr is the length of the substring, we need to subtract the index of the opening parantheses, so:

```
substr(columnname,instr(columnname,"(") + 1, instr(columnname,")") - instr(columnname,"(") - 1)
```

should do the trick

Answer (score -1):

Mysql's regexes don't support capturing or replacing. They're purely for matching. You'd need to use regular string operations to do the actual extraction:

```
SELECT ...string stuff here...
FROM yourtable
WHERE OUTCNTCTNOTE regexp ....
```

If your strings are fairly 'regular' and you don't have to worry about multiple sets of brackets in any field, then using [`LOCATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) and [`SUBSTR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) would do the trick.