# mySql retrieving data between square brackets

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have strings of data in a field named `content`, one record may look something like:

```
loads of text ... [attr1] some text [attr2] more text [attr3] more text etc...
```

What I'm looking to do is get all the text within the square brackets; so that I can put it into a PHP array. Is this even possible with mySql?

I've seen the following post: [Looking to extract data between parentheses in a string via MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072402/looking-to-extract-data-between-parentheses-in-a-string-via-mysql), but they are looking to only extract one value from between their parentheses, I have an unknown number of them. After reading that post I've though of doing something like the following;

```
SELECT substr(content,instr(content,"["), instr(content,"]")) as attrList from myTable
```

Which would grab me the following:

```
[attr1] some text [attr2] some more text [attr3]
```

and I can use PHP to strip the rest of the text out and then explode the string into an array, but is there a better way to do this just using mySql where I can retrieve something like:

```
[attr1][attr2][attr3]
```

I was thinking perhaps regex, but I see that just returns a true of false which doesn't help me a lot.

Comment: PostgreSQL can do that I have heard. For MySQL I think there is some user procedure you can use for that. I don’t recall exactly now though.

Comment: No this is best done client side (i.e. in PHP).  Multiple regex matches per line can be problematic and even more so if multiline input is supplied.  Also it is not a good idea to send lots of data to SQL especially "loads of text" as there are network packet/command processing limits.  You can invest in MySQL functions/modules/stored-proc on server side but this can end up making application more complex to deploy/setup/maintain.  There is usually good methods for working with client side code, not with MySQL server side custom code.

Comment: Thanks, I can't switch databases unfortunately and @DarrylMiles I thought that might be the case, I thought I'd ask just on the off chance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After even more research, I'm not sure it's possible in mySql, and I might need the results in string or array form depending on where I'm using them in my app.

So I've created a new method to return the list after I've got the data from the database (with a little help from this post: [PHP: Capturing text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104473/php-capturing-text-between-square-brackets#10104517)):

```
public function attrList($array=false)
{
    preg_match_all("/\[.*?\]/",$this->content,$matches);

    $params = str_replace(array('[',']'),'',$matches[0]);

    return ($array===false) ? implode(', ',$params) : $params;
}
```